# Phonegap/Cordova geolocation alert what near a specific location

Tags: google-maps, cordova, geolocation, phonegap

I need some guidence in finding out how I can fire an alert when my location is located near a specified location.

I guess then would use google map and geolocation but I am not sure.

I would also like to be able to show some code but after doing countless google searches I can't find anything and I don't know what to look for.

I'll be using phonegap / cordova.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?`enter code here`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for a geofence plugin like this one: https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence

This will let you monitor when your device transitions into and out of custom geofences / location zones you set up.

Add this to your project using `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-geofence` and follow the usage guide in their readme.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Convert Destination Address to lat lng values
     var specificlocation = {
      lat: -13.26589,
      lng: 98.365297
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        //onDeviceReaddy
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayAndWatch, locError);
    }


    // user Current Position
    function displayAndWatch(position) {
        setCurrentPosition(position);
        watchCurrentPosition();
    }

    function setCurrentPosition(pos) {
        var image = 'img/ic_CurrentLocationmap.png';

        currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: image,
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                pos.coords.latitude,
                pos.coords.longitude
            ),
            title: "Current Location"
        });
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
            pos.coords.latitude,
            pos.coords.longitude
        ));
    }

 //Watch User/phone current location
    function watchCurrentPosition() {
        var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
            function (position) {
                setMarkerPosition(
                    currentPositionMarker,
                    position
                );
            });
    }

    function setMarkerPosition(marker, position) {
        marker.setPosition(
            new google.maps.LatLng(
                position.coords.latitude,
                position.coords.longitude)
        );
        var center = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        }
        map.setCenter(center);

       //Check distance between specificlocation and user/phone current location
        var distance = DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(center.lat, center.lng, specificlocation.lat,
            specificlocation.lng, "K")

        //with in 100 Meters
        if (distance < 0.1) {
            navigator.notification.confirm(
                'You are Reached specificlocation Address', // message
                onConfirmReached, //Callback
                'AppName', // title
                ['No', 'Yes'] // buttonLabels
            );
        }
    function locError(error) {
        // the current position could not be located
    }

    function onConfirmReached(buttonIndex) {
        if (buttonIndex == 2) {
            //Alert result
        }
    }

 //Find Distance between Two coordinations 
    function DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit) {
        try {
            unit = "K"
            var radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1 / 180
            var radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2 / 180
            var radlon1 = Math.PI * lon1 / 180
            var radlon2 = Math.PI * lon2 / 180
            var theta = lon1 - lon2
            var radtheta = Math.PI * theta / 180
            var dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(
                radtheta);
            dist = Math.acos(dist)
            dist = dist * 180 / Math.PI
            dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515
            //Calculate Kilometer
            if (unit == "K") {
                dist = dist * 1.609344
            }
            //Calculate Miles
            if (unit == "N") {
                dist = dist * 0.8684
            }
            return dist;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```